# Permissions Manager

Tags: windows

I would like to know if there is any tool/software (paid or free) that will do the following thing.

I have several software that the users asks permissions for it (eg. the ERP, Document Management System and more) these permissions change quite often. I would like a tool where a manager would login to the particular software and check the software he/she needs to give access to an associate and check the permissions. Then I would receive and email which will say that this particular users needs a permission update.